# Auditing Security Vulnerabilities of Centos 6.5 Products

Tags: security

I am researching ways to Audit Security Vulnerabilities on Centos using the practical example here:

[https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Practical_Examples.html
][1]

It shows openscap using **com.redhat.rhsa-all.xml and com.redhat.rhsa-all.xccdf.xml**.  I have configured a Centos 6.5 system with openscap and scanner 1.2.8.  The scans run, without any noticeable errors, but it is saying that all tests are passing.

Is this a suitable way to scan for vulnerabilities against installed products on Centos systems?

I am kind of new to this, is there another OVAL file I should be using or is there some messagging I need to do to the redhat com.redhat.rhsa-all.xccdf.xml file to get it to work on Centos?

Here is an example of a vulnerability I would like to test for, it is passing:   RHSA-2016:0675: java-1.7.0-openjdk security update

Comment: BTW, I would like to add a tag named openscap but I apparently don't have enough reputation. Oh and thanks for the down vote with no explanation whoever that was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out OVAL files for CentOS systems are readily available here [oval.cisecurity.org](https://oval.cisecurity.org/repository/download)

To obtain a proper OVAL file for a Centos 6.5 system uaing openscap and scanner versions 1.2.8 make these selections from the download page:

- Versions v5.11.1(v5.10 also seems to work)
- Classes patch
- Scroll down to the Centos section and select centos linux 6

This will download a file named centos_linux_6.xml

This is the command I use to create a report

```
/usr/bin/oscap oval eval --results results.xml --report report.html centos_linux_6.xml
```